# How to handle RootViewController from GLKViewController which is inherited in UIViewController class in iOS?

Tags: ios6, opengl-es-2.0

I need to include `OpenGL ES 2.0` functions for video rendering in iOS, which is handled by the `GLKViewController` class. The problem is that, my main class is `UIViewcontroller` and I need to derive `GLKViewController` inside it (I have taken `GLCameraRipple` example as reference). `UIViewController` handles the `rootviewcontroller` and it is not allowing creating a texture for rendering my video, even though image data from sample buffer is coming fine. I am confused with `appDelegate` function where `UIViewController` is called instead of `GLKViewController` (as per `GLCameraRipple` example). I am new to `OpenGL`. Please someone let me know how to handle this correctly and I am really stuck at this point and do not know how to move ahead.

Thanks in advance.

---

EDIT:
Hello Valentin Radu,
Thank you so much for the reply.
Having gone through your reply and the link suggested by you and working around them, my question still remains unanswered. Let me elaborate my case. I am supposed to capture a YUV video on iOS device (iPhone or iPod), encode and decode the captured YUV video and display decoded video back. As far as the capture, encode and decode are concerned everything is working flawless. As it takes significant time converting YUV pixel format to BGRA pixel format I have opted for openGL (referred GLCamera ripple example). As far as my app is concerned the main class is UIViewController. For displaying YUV data I have made use of GLKViewController class. Question is how to access the GLKViewController class from the UIViewController class. I cannot call GLKViewController or GLKView from the appdelegate. The flow is something like, appdelegate  UIViewController  GLKViewController (GLKView called inside this class) display YUV pixel data. I have no other option but to follow this flow as UIViewController sits on the top handling other dependant projects. Next part of the question. As per Valentin Radu’s suggestion I have tried using GLKView and tried rendering my video. Here I am stuck with handling rootViewController if the GLKView is defined inside GLKViewController. Please pardon me and correct me wherever I am wrong.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You don't need `GLKViewController` to set up your GLKView. You can set it up individually very easy and subclass it too hook up to the rendering notifications as I described here: http://cocoaexposed.com/post/40459534493/set-up-opengl-without-xcode